# how to remove ads url / ads search url from search engine

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools

I am facing one issue on chrome search engine. Whenever I searched something it shows ads urls why? 
Please check below the image. Can I add an ad blocker extension?

[image]

Answer (score -2, accepted):

These 3 steps should solve your problem:

**1.** Download *adwcleaner* from here https://www.malwarebytes.com/adwcleaner/ and run it. After clean, restart PC.

**2.** Download free trial of Malewarebytes from here https://pl.malwarebytes.com/ and perform FULL SCAN.

**3.** Download *HitmanPro* from here https://www.hitmanpro.com/en-us/hmp.aspx and perform FULL SCAN. This is not freeware, but 30 days are free. Restart PC.

After these steps, your browser should be clean.

And, one for-future advice - before you will download something from the Internet, or install, read carefully while downloading/installing. Problem of your kind are usually because of installing some freeware software with hidden aggrements to install web browser's extensions, which are later hard to remove.